# Sublime text 2 - Zip open files with full path name and dir structure

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a plugin or a macro, that creates a tar ball or a zip of all opened files / tabs in Sublime Text 2.

If not, how to make a plugin that does that?

I was checking the [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html) of Sublime Text 2, only to know that there is no method that gets the full path of all open files.

However, I see that we have an option when we right click in any file - "Copy file path".

Which method it calls? Can I replicate the method to all tabs switching one by one? If yes, then how to cycle through open tabs one by one using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window#views` to get all the views (as a list). Then iterate on each view and use  `view#file_name` to get the files. As for creating zips, take a look at the [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile) library.

For your particular case, I would create a window command. You can then bind that to a key combination or add it as a command palette entry. Finally, to set the visible view, you can use `window#focus_view`. You may also need `window#focus_group` if you have multiple groups.